# Can the WKB approximation be used for this double well potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential, schroedinger-equation, semiclassical

For a positive constant $C$, the double well potential $V(x) = -C|x| $ exists between two infinitely high potential walls at $x=a$ and $x=-a$.

I wish to use the WKB approximation to obtain an equation determining the energy eigenvalues for $E<0$. From this eigenvalue equation, I should be able to determine the minimum value of $C$ required for one of these energies to exist.

Is this possible with the WKB approximation? It seems to be a symmetric version of the triangular well potential. However, the classically forbidden region for this potential contains (I think) 2 turning points, along with the other 2 turning points at the infinite walls. Could one use the symmetry of the problem to solve for the region $x<0$ and then complete the solution using parity arguments?

Comment: As for symmetry — yes of course, why not? The potential is symmetric, so there are even and odd solutions of the TISE. Not sure why you want WKB approach though. Why should it help? Airy functions are the way to go if you just want to solve the TISE (or even generate the equation for eigenvalues). Finally, I wouldn't assume an eigenvalue exists at $E=0$. You have bounded motion here, so it would be a coincidence if you got an eigenvalue at such a special energy.

Comment: Hi Ruslan, thanks for your reply. I want to use the WKB approximation because I am working through Merzbacher's Quantum textbook. In his chapter on WKB, this is one of the problems he asks. If you want more context, here is a link to the PDF of the textbook. Its problem 3, page 134. Cheers http://www.physics.smu.edu/scalise/P6335fa19/solutions/Merzbacher.pdf

Comment: Hi @user273734. Welcome to Phys.SE. Consider to incorporate comment and other info into post.